# TabLayout does not reflect ViewPager adapter's change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want a tabbed dialogue box. So I added a TabLayout, and a ViewPager below it. I created a FragmentPagerAdapter, and called the ViewPager's `setAdapter()` with it. Then I called TabLayout's `setupWithViewPager()` with the ViewPager.

Now, I increased the count of the FragmentPagerAdapter, and added a new fragment to it, and called `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The problem is that new tab did not appear.

After trying a lot of things, I called the TabLayout's `setupWithViewPager()` again with the same ViewPager. It did make the new tab appear, but I am not sure whether this is the correct approach. Why doesn't the TabLayout automatically reflect the changes to the ViewPager (new fragment)?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is quite simple, but needs one more thing. If you can see what method `setupWithViewPager()` does, it also **adds** `TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener` to viewPager, so whenever you call `setupWithViewPager()` you add one more listener. You should call `viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners()` to remove old lisetners, just before you call `setupWithViewPager()` and it will be ok.

In project, I'm working on, we are using a bit different solution, but it is because of using custom tab views with some specific behavior: 
You can registerDataSetObserver on your viewpageradapter. Whenever you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` your `DataSetObserver.onChanged()` will be called too. In this method we are manipulating with tabs in tablayout (creating new/removing old).. We also create new onTabSelectedListeners for tabLayout.

Comment: I was stuck in this for 2 days . Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners() , I did         tabLayout.clearOnTabSelectedListeners()

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Observer as suggested above. Add a new tab for the new added item in your this.mAdapter used by your this.viewPager and this.tabLayout.

```
       mAdapter.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();
            if (tabLayout.getTabCount() < mAdapter.getCount()) {
                tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(mAdapter.getPageTitle(mAdapter.getCount() - 1)), mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        }
    });
```